# Put elements of a 1D vector into a 3D matrix using another matrix of positions

Tags: matlab

I have a vector of data points which were saved from a 3D array by some other program in one big list. The vector is nk elements long. nk = nx*ny*nz where nx, ny and nz are the dimensions of the original 3D array.

The position of a data point in the original array is stored in a (nk x 3) array, arranged with each row (position(k,:)) giving the (i,j,k) position of the corresponding data point.

I can't use reshape on my data array as the position vector is not simple (it depends on some stuff to do with how the data was generated - it isn't completely random - but I won't necessarily know what it looks like beforehand).

If the nk vector is called 'data', the nk x 3 position array is called 'position' and the output array is called 'data_reshaped' then currently I am doing the following:

```
for k = 1:nk
    data_reshaped(position(k,1),position(k,2),position(k,3)) = data(k);
end
```

This is really slow - is there some faster method without knowing much about what 'position' looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) function:

```
data_reshaped = zeros(nx, ny, nz);
data_reshaped( sub2ind([nx ny nz], position(:,1), ...
                                   position(:,2), ...
                                   position(:,3)) ) = data;
```

Comment: That looks really close (and much faster) but data_reshaped comes out as a nk vector rather than a nx*ny*nz array. (Do I just use reshape: data_reshaped_again = reshape(data_reshaped,nx,ny,nz)?)