# Matlab processing data from text file

Tags: matlab

I try to read data from a text file. I can do it via import. It works fine. 
My data imported as: 
    UserID|SportID|Rating

There are a lot of users that can like any sport with any rating for example:

```
User|SportID|Rating
1      2       10
1      3        5
2      1       10
2      3        2
```

I try to create a new matrix like below

```
UserID  Sport1  Sport2  Sport3
 1      (null)    10      5
 2        10    (null)    2
```

I tried to this via "for" and "loop" however there are almost 2000 user and 1000 sports and their data is almost 100000. How can I do this?

Comment: If you have parallel processing you can use a `parfor` loop.

Comment: What problem are you actually having? Is it too slow? Do you run out of memory? Is your problem actually in creating your matrix or in looking things up?

Comment: It was too slow.. but i used kronos answer it works like charm :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
% Test Input
inputVar = [1 2 10; 1 3 5; 2 1 10; 2 3 2]; 

% Determine number of users, and sports to create the new table
numSports = max(inputVar(1:end,2));
numUsers = max(inputVar(1:end,1));
newTable = NaN(numUsers, numSports);

% Iterate for each row of the new table (# of users)
for ii = 1:numUsers
    % Determine where the user rated from input mat, which sport he/she rated, and the rating
    userRating = find(inputVar(1:end,1) == ii);
    sportIndex = inputVar(userRating, 2)';
    sportRating = inputVar(userRating, 3)';
    newTable(ii, sportIndex) = sportRating; % Crete the new table based on the ratings.
end

newTable
```

Which produced the following:

```
newTable =

   NaN    10     5
    10   NaN     2
```

This would only have to run for the amount of users that are in your input table.

Comment: @MichaelAdam: Hi, I have a question: aren't `sub2ind` or `accumarray`  faster than this method? or `sparse`. Can you explain why have you chosen this method?

Comment: @pm89 perhaps this is an easier to understand answer.  Your answer, though it may be faster, is a bit more confusing to some.

Comment: @KronoS: Thanks! I was really curious to know the reason, since the original question is interesting for me.

Answer (score 2):

To do this fast, you can use a sparse matrix with one dimension `UserID` and the other `Sports`.  The sparse matrix will behave for most things like a normal matrix.  Construct it like so

```
out = sparse(User, SportID, Rating)
```

where `User`, `SportID` and `Rating` are the vectors corresponding to the columns of your text file.

Note 1: for duplicate of `User` and `SportID` the `Rating` will be summed.

Note 2: empty entries, as were written as `(null)` in the question are not stored in sparse matrices, only the non-zero ones (that is the main point of sparse matrices).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have already defined `null` as a number for simplification.

```
Null = -1; % or any other value which could not be a rating.
```

Considering:

```
nSports = 1000; % Number of sports
nUsers = 2000; % Number of users
```

Pre-allocate the result:

```
Rating_Mat = ones(nUsers, nSports) * Null; % Pre-allocation
```

Then use [**`sub2ind`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) (similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16923028/1698972)):

```
Rating_Mat (sub2ind([nUsers nSports], User, SportID) = Rating;
```

Or [**`accumarray`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
Rating_Mat = accumarray([User, SportID], Rating);
```

assuming that `User` and `SportID` are `Nx1`.

Hope it helps.